# personal_options hook on Wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, hooks

I have a working script that hooks to user profile. This is my hook:

```
add_action('personal_options', array(&$this,'show_bounce_email_warning_to_user'),10,1);
```

As you can see it will show bounce email warnings at the profile page. This works well when the user access his user profile by this URL for example:

```
http://my-multisite.com/wp-admin/profile.php
```

However most users do not login using the root admin page. But to their specific websites (which is a subdomain of the multisite) for example:

```
http://userwebsite.my-multisite.com/wp-admin/
```

But the email warning at the personal options page (at user profile) does not appear in any of the user websites under the multisite:

```
http://userwebsite.my-multisite.com/wp-admin/profile.php
```

I need the warnings to appear in all user profiles that the user is logged-in. Not just when accessing the root WP admin URL.

What is the hook to use? Any tips is highly appreciated thanks!

Cheers.

**UPDATE:**

This is my code for show_bounce_email_warning_to_user function:

```
 function show_bounce_email_warning_to_user($user_id) {

global $current_user;

//Get user ID
$user_id=$current_user->ID;

//Get user email
$user_email_affected=$current_user->user_email;

    //Check the status of mailer_bounce_email_detected meta key
    $mailer_bounce_email_detected_status=get_user_meta($user_id, 'mailer_bounce_email_detected', true);

    if ($mailer_bounce_email_detected_status=='true') {

?>

<div class="alert">
    <strong>Bounce email detected, please update your email address</strong>
</div>
<?php       

}


}
```

It is fully working but I have problems making that appear in user profiles of the user in his/her other site in a multisite environment. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure the hook is the issue?  Does your code print anything if there's nothing found?  You might need to look into [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog).

Comment: Where have you placed this code? And what is the code for `show_bounce_email_warning_to_user`?

Comment: @PatJ: Thanks for the tips on switch_to_blog. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I place this code in the plugin __construct. I will update my question for the code on show bounce email. Thanks.